# Nicer way to provide Date Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I create a date time range like this in rails:

```
last_3_months = (Date.today - 3.month)..Date.today
next_40_days = Date.today..(Date.today + 40.days)
```

Is there a nicer way in Ruby to make it more readable?
Something like:

```
last_3_months = 3.months.ago.to_range
next_40_days = 40.days.from_now.to_range
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails does not provide any helper methods to create date ranges from dates. So a short answer to your question would be "no".

However, you can slightly improve your code readability by using method of `ActiveSupport::Duration`. It is returned when you do things like `3.months`.

```
3.month.ago.to_date..Date.current
Date.current..40.days.from_now.to_date
```

And if you decide to monkeypatch a class to add additional functionality, it should be `ActiveSupport::Duration` and not built-in `Time`/`DateTime` classes.

---

#### NOTE:

You are mixing `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` class instances with instances of classes that don't support time zones (`Date`). `3.months.ago` returns an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` and you are adding the other side of the range without any timezone information. This may lead to hard to catch bugs. So, instead it is better to use `Date.current` instead of `Date.today`.

Comment: BIG plus one on the Note.

Answer (score 1):

You can "monkey-patch" `Time` class as follows:

```
class Time
  def to_range
    self > Date.today ? (Date.today..self.to_date) : (self.to_date..Date.today)
  end
end

3.days.ago.to_range
# => Mon, 20 Jun 2016..Thu, 23 Jun 2016 
3.days.from_now.to_range
# => Thu, 23 Jun 2016..Sun, 26 Jun 2016
```

Comment: I'd avoid monkey patching ruby classes :/

Comment: That approach solves specified problem. Its convenience is out of the scope of current question. Btw, we don't change behavior of existing method, so there will be minimal side-effects.

Comment: "minimal" side-effects is what makes me nervous. Personally I resist the temptation to change the behavior of a class provided by Ruby. To each his own, I suppose, though